# Java 8 DateTime Format Date + Offset

Tags: java, date, datetime, formatting, java-time

I have to construct a `XMLGregorianCalendar` for a Webservice which expects a date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd+01:00`, where the value after `+` is derived from the time zone offsett.

So far I have experimented with:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterDateWithOffset = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddZZ");

XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(zonedDateTime.format(formatterDateWithOffset));
```

But this results in an `IllegalArgumentExcpetion` because the formatter produces `2017-09-29+0200`

Is it possible to define a format string for the desired format?

Comment: Why do you use ZonedDateTime and not LocalDateTime?

Comment: Did you try `yyyy-MM-ddZZZZ`? JavaDoc: "One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130', ... letters outputs the full form of localized offset"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the JavaDoc on `DateTimeFormatter` you'll see this:

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'. ... Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

Thus `DateTimeFormatter formatterDateWithOffset = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddxxx");` should work.

In my comment I suggested using `ZZZZ` because the JavaDoc hinted at that as well but it will add the `GMT` part too (`ZZZZZ` seems to work even though the JavaDoc states: "Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional *second if non-zero*, with colon" ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing you can create an instance of XMLGregorianCalendar passing to it year, month etc:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(year, month....)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46487981/7605325) said, one alternative is to use `xxx` (or `XXX`), as [explained in javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-). The only difference between those is when the offset is zero: `XXX` formats to `Z`, while `xxx` formats to `+00:00`:

```
Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
-------  -----  --------------------------
XXX      3      appendOffset("+HH:MM","Z")
xxx      3      appendOffset("+HH:MM","+00:00")
```

Anyway, just choose one of them (I've tested with both, using a `ZonedDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` and both worked):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddXXX");
String str = formatter.format(zonedDateTime);
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(str);
```

---

If you have a `ZonedDateTime`, it's easier to convert it to a `GregorianCalendar`, and then pass it to your `DatatypeFactory`:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
GregorianCalendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from(zonedDateTime);
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
```

A tricky detail is that, when using the `String` pattern above (with only the date), the result will have the time fields (hour, minute, second and millisecond) set to zero, while converting to `GregorianCalendar` will use the time set in the `ZonedDateTime`.

But you can set the time to midnight before converting it to `GregorianCalendar`:

```
// convert to calendar (set the time to 00:00:00.000)
GregorianCalendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from(zonedDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
```

With this, the result will be the same as using the `String`.